# Property 'style' does not exist on type but still work

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm having this problem with react-native. When I use the **HideWithKeyboard** component, I have to set the `style={{flex:7}}` to display correctly.

I'm getting an IDE (VSCode) error, but the style is working properly. Is there some way to fix this error or will this really fail in some cases?

Comment: Can you please give the error your getting? Also just to clarify, are you applying the style directly to the HideWithKeyboard component? As in <HideWithKeyboard style = {{flex:7}}>

Answer (score 0):

Restart the TS language server, or, restart VSCode.